# Get Paypal Sandbox to remain signed in for longer than 5 minutes

Tags: authentication, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am sick of the absolute pile of rubbish that is the paypal sandbox for numerous reasons but one thing that is annoying me especially at the moment is the login cookie length. It lasts all of 5 minutes before you have to log in again. You lose the page you were on and end up back at the dashboard after punching in your password for the 500th time that day.

I am testing reference transactions (another completely embarassing sandbox implementation) and whenever I go to check or change something in the account I am using to pay I am logged out.

Is there any way to force it to keep me logged in for longer?

Comment: Yessss! In the last few hours, I've logged in, with stupid 2FA about 20 times 

Answer (score 0):

if you are logging into another account to pay, this is why you are being logged out. try using another browser, or private browsing to keep your logins separate.

Comment: He mentioned he's using reference transactions, so that wouldn't be the issue.

Comment: As above, I'm using reference transactions and the login is simply to check the results of the reference transactions and force errors etc

Answer (score -3):

I work with the sandbox every day and I don't have any issues in general.  Not sure why you would be talking so badly about it.

The session thing is something PayPal does (like any financial website) to protect people.  Yes, it's the sandbox, but it's meant to simulate the live PayPal site, so that session will act the same.

As for your comments about reference transactions, I guess you'll need to expand on that.  I've thoroughly tested reference transactions in the sandbox for numerous projects and have never had any issues with it.

One thing I could recommend that would help with typing in the password over and over (as well as help you maintain good password standard practices in general) is to use [LastPass](https://lastpass.com/).  You'll never have to type a password again.

Another option would be to setup a local solution using the [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) and [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) APIs.  For example, I've started something like that with my [PayPal Glass](http://paypal-glass.angelleye.com/) project, which is essentially replicating the PayPal interface with my [PHP class library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  Notice that I don't have any sign in protection on that at all, so it never times out or anything.

It's a little more effort up front, but you can save lots of time in the future with projects like you're working on.  If you're working with PHP you could grab that [PayPal Glass project from GitHub](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass) and just use it with your own sandbox.

Comment: I have been using the PayPal sandbox for years and have had nothing but issues with it. It's horrendously slow, very temperamental and quite bug ridden. Today for about 2 hours I couldn't access any other page apart from the transactions screen. Any other link hung for 30 seconds then loaded the transactions page again. It wouldn't use the sandbox accounts secondary payment method for 3 hours today while testing reference transactions then suddenly started working again. It's a mess.